# While I've set Windows to French Regional format and comma as a decimal symbol, the UWP CurrencyFormatter still displays a dot

Tags: windows, uwp

For a UWP app, I'm wrote the following converter.

```
public class CurrencyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private readonly CurrencyFormatter _userCurrencyFormatter;
    private readonly CultureInfo _userCulture;

    public CurrencyConverter()
    {
        var userCurrency = Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences.Currencies[0];
        _userCurrencyFormatter = new CurrencyFormatter(userCurrency);
        _userCulture = new CultureInfo(Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences.HomeGeographicRegion);
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language) => value == null ? null : _userCurrencyFormatter.Format((double)(decimal)value);

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language) => decimal.TryParse((string)value, NumberStyles.Number, _userCulture, out var result) ? (decimal?)result : null;
}
```

My setup is:

- windows Region to France
- Regional Format to French
- decimal symbol to comma
- Keyboard layout to French(France)

However,

- My numeric pad on the keyboard still displays a dot rather than a comma
- The converter displays currency with € but with dot rather than comma

UPDATE:

- decimal are displayed with a dot in `TextBlock`
- however, I have to use a comma when I enter a decimal into a `TextBox`

Here are some screenshots of my setup

[image: decimal separator to comma]
[image: regional setup to France]
[image: Keyboard layout to France]

UPDATE:

Here is a screenshot of my converter where we see that despite the language being French and the RegionCode being FR, the `DecimalFormatter` displays a dot as a separator rather than a comma.

[image]

Comment: Is French the primary language in Language screen in Settings?

Comment: No it's English.

Answer (score 1):

UWP apps use the the "primary" language as the app display language - so if you have English as the first language in system Settings, the app will use English as both `Culture` and `UICulture` and hence the formatting will match English as well.

Comment: It's likely the answer, I'll have to check. Yet it's not logical that UWP ignores the regional format and decimal separator.

Comment: Especially knowing that I HAD to use a comma to enter decimal values in TextBox.

Comment: It is weird, I will check further, maybe I am just missing something too

Comment: I'm trying to revisit that isse so I added a new screenshot.